# populate dropdown with two fields in rails 4 ajax

Tags: ruby, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having trouble populating a field with two columns concatenated. For example: I want to populate Worker field with both first name and last name in AJAX rails 4.

Currently I'm populating with just first name using

```
<%= collection_select(:work_order ,:worker_id ,Worker.all, :id ,:first_name) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
<%= f.input :user_id, :as => :select, :collection => [[current_user.firstname+' ' +current_user.lastname, current_user.id]], :label=>"Names"%>
```